# How do i make a post request to linkedin api and share content using python

Tags: python, django, linkedin-api

I have to add a feature in  django web application in which users are logged in through linkedin and i want to share content to linkedin whenever a user recommend an article on site.

Comment: take a look at the related questions on the right.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to check [the LinkedIn API](http://developer.linkedin.com/apis) for the API Documentation and [the Requests Module](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/) for making the POST request.

If there is an official library or if you can find an API Wrapper, you can use it instead of making the POST requests yourself.